# Got an answer right but don't know how or why. Need an explanation

Tags: c, arrays

I recently did an exam and there was a bonus question and I was the only person who got it right. I am just as curious as much as my class mates are on how I got it right.

The question was:
Use this array: `int a[5] = {5, 1, 15, 20, 25};`

Use these variables: `int i, j, m;`

Use this base code:

```
i = /*Enter Code*/;
j = /*Enter Code*/;
m = /*Enter Code*/;
printf("%d, %d, %d", i, j, m);
```

Get this answer: `3, 2, 15`

There were a bunch of conditions but the main was that we were only allowed to use the array and one '1' and one '++' per variable equals.

I got the answer right through trial and error but I have no idea how I got it right and how it is right. Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
   int a[5] = {5, 1, 15, 20, 25};
   int i, j, m;
   i = ++a[1];
   j = a[1]++;
   m = a[i++];
   printf("%d, %d, %d", i, j, m);
   _getch();
   return 0;
}
```

I am purely curious about how I got the right answer. Any explanation would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happened then you stepped through your code with a debugger, inspecting var values at each step, after you compiled and linked it yourself?

Comment: @MartinJames I got the correct answer of '3, 2, 15', if that is what you mean. I am not really sure what this question asks.

Comment: 'I have no idea how I got it right and how it is right' - to find out, if you have not already done so, step through the code with your debugger, inspecting var values at each step.

Comment: It should be easy for you, after all, you wrote the code and it gives the correct result.  You obviously have some idea of what is happening, so just step through and complete your explanation document.

Comment: HInt: What was the basis of your _trial and error_?

Comment: @MartinJames Oh, I understand. Yeah I have done that, but it doesn't give me a very in depth explanation, that is why I came to stack overflow.

Comment: I'm just curious why so many down votes? Has SO become so toxic these days, that every question which is "easy" for you gets down votes? Look at the questions 7 years ago, "What is the difference between char and integer" and it has 450+ up votes. This question is under the rules and it was understandable, it includes code and it's perfectly clear what the OP wanted to know.

Comment: @Mirakurun it was not downvoted because it's easy.

Comment: @Mirakurun IMHO, 'toxic' would be, when faced with a 'perform this task and provide complete explanation' homework, a user copied some working code from a fellow student and dumped it on SO to get the textual explanation without any effort by him/herself to understand it or trace through it.

Comment: @MartinJames I think you got me wrong Martin. This isn't homework, it was in a written exam that happened weeks ago. I was just completely curious on how I got this answer. Me and a mate were looking at this for a long time and couldn't figure it out. All we knew was that it was right and that I used trial and error to get he right answer. So I came to SO to get some insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, just look at the three statements:

```
i = ++a[1];
```

This changes `a[1]` to `2`, and assigns that value to `i`.

```
j = a[1]++;
```

This sets `j` to `2`, and changes `a[1]` to `3`.

```
m = a[i++];
```

This sets `m` to `15`, and changes `i` to `3`.

So the final values that are printed the required ones, `3, 2, 15`.

If you ran this in a debugger, you could watch all the variables and see it happen statement by statement.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense thanks. I kind of knew how 2 and 15 were achieved but not 3. Thank a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Like everyone said, just step through your code with a debugger, or manually :

at beginning

```
a[5] = {5, 1, 15, 20, 25}
```

after `i = ++a[1];`

```
a[5] = {5, 2, 15, 20, 25}
i = 2
```

because the pre-incrementation ++ will modify a[1] before affecting him to i.

after   `j = a[1]++;`

```
a[5] = {5, 3, 15, 20, 25}
i = 2
j = 2
```

because the post-incrementation ++ will modify a[1] after affecting him to j.

after  `m = a[i++];`

```
a[5] = {5, 3, 15, 20, 25}
i = 3
j = 2
m = 15
```

because the post incrementation will modify the value of i after the affectation to m, so at the time of affectation, i will be equal to 2, which a[2] = 15.

You need to understand the difference between ++a and a++ (and when the two incrementation will take place).